# How can we call the same @Path that returns (@Produces) a different format?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I have two paths as :

```
   @Path("Rectangle")
   @GET
   @Produces("application/xml")
   @Consumes("application/xml")
```

and,

```
   @Path("Rectangle")
   @GET
   @Produces("application/json")
   @Consumes("application/xml")
```

When I hit my API on localhost, I always get the XML response. What would I need to do so that I can get the JSON response for the same `@Path` ?

Comment: Change the path or change the consumes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as per the [docs](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#reps-and-types) you can specify multiple content-types for the same end point

```
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
```

and based on the request header `Accept` the Response will have the most accepted content-type

so, you need one method and it should look like this

```
@Path("Rectangle")
@GET
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
@Consumes("application/xml")
```

now the client need to send the header `Accept` with the content type they want to receive, example:

```
Accept: application/xml
```

this will cause the response header "content-type" to be `content-type: application/xml`

you can also use the `Accept` header to format your response

Comment: This should be accepted. I wonder `user1650978` will do, though.

Comment: @JinKwon yes, i think OP have forget that :|